# Java Selenium - in separate Class method is working, in POM - NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors

I spent two days on this, and can't seem to find where is the error. In a separate Class, the code is working. In `pom.xml` I get an error: `NullPointerException: Cannot invoke LoginPage.loginCustomer() because this.loginPage is null`.

```
public class _BasePage {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private WebDriverWait driverWait;
}
```

with parametrised construktor, getters and setters. Then, a class `BankManagerMenu`:

```
public class BankManagerMenu extends _BasePage {
        
    private By addCustomer = By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[1]");
        public BankManagerMenu(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait driverWait){
            super(driver,driverWait);
        }
    
        public boolean addCustomerBtn(){
            return this.getDriver().findElement(this.addCustomer).isDisplayed();
    }
```

And a Class `LoginPage`

```
public class LoginPage extends _BasePage {


private By customerButton = By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Customer Login']");
private By bankManagerButton = By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Bank Manager Login')]");

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait driverWait) {
    super(driver, driverWait);
}
public void loginBankManager() {
    new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(20)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(bankManagerButton)).click();
}

public void loginCustomer() {
    this.getDriver().findElement(this.customerButton).click();

}}
```

Finally, this is my Test Class

```
public class TestPage {
private WebDriver driver;
private WebDriverWait driverWait;
private LoginPage loginPage;
private BankManagerMenu bankManagerMenu;

public TestPage(){}

@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Raven\\Desktop\\QA\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
//    WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(15));
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.globalsqa.com/angularJs-protractor/BankingProject/#/login");
}

@Test
public void loginAsBankManager(){
    this.loginPage.loginBankManager();
  //  Assert.assertTrue(this.bankManagerMenu.addCustomerBtn());
}}
```

Comment: where is the line that has that error ? , cannot find any "this.loginPage" in your code

Comment: loginPage is uninitialized... there's no "new LoginPage()" called.  " super(driver, driverWait);" will never happen since it's being called as if it were a static class.  eg: this.loginPage.loginBankManager();   So you can either re-factor to treat your page objects as static classes, or pass the driver references to the constructors.